# Error in connecting to AlloyDB database with IAM user

Tags: python, google-cloud-sql, google-alloydb

For Postgre Cloudsql, we  have to use google cloud-sql-python-connector to connect to DB. When we establish a connection using IAM user, we don't have to pass any password if we pass a flag `enable_iam_auth` as true . I confirmed this  by looking at source-code of this connector that password is optional (Line  58 [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector/blob/main/google/cloud/sql/connector/pg8000.py))
However, for AlloyDB, we have to use alloydb-python-connector and when I am not passing any password for IAM user, it is resulting an error. This can be confirmed from source code where password is not optional (Line 50 [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/alloydb-python-connector/blob/b487f31790a42bda20b4e43a0334c2ce3e9a5994/google/cloud/alloydb/connector/pg8000.py)). I tried setting password as blank string or None  but it didn't work.I also tried setting the flag `enable_iam_auth` but I got an error that it's an invalid argument.

The error is because alloy-db-connector has not specified any default value while poping password. Is there any other way we can use this connector with AlloyDB?

Comment: Connecting AlloyDB instance is a bit different from PostgreSQL. AlloyDB instance doesn't have IAM-based authentication enabled. You may check this documentation on [managin IAM authentication](https://cloud.google.com/alloydb/docs/manage-iam-authn). Please be advised that this is still in pre-GA (alpha/beta/early access) and may have limited support/functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned on [this Github issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/alloydb-python-connector/issues/151)

This is because automatic IAM database authentication is not currently a supported feature of the [AlloyDB Python Connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/alloydb-python-connector). It is currently being worked and will be released in the near future. There is an [open feature request](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/alloydb-python-connector/issues/152) as a public tracking bug for this feature.

However, you can actually configure/wire your own SQLAlchemy engine to connect using IAM authentication with some very minimal code.

We have an [example that uses this method with psycopg2](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/alloydb-python-connector/blob/main/tests/system/test_psycopg2_direct_connection.py#L30) to connect directly without using the AlloyDB Python Connector.

Additional steps to enable IAM database authentication on an AlloyDB instance can be found https://cloud.google.com/alloydb/docs/manage-iam-authn and make sure all steps have been followed in detail.

TLDR steps;

- [ ] Enabled IAM authentication on the AlloyDB instance via `alloydb.iam_authentication` flag
- [ ] Granted the IAM Principal (user or service account) the `Cloud AlloyDB Client` and `Cloud AlloyDB Database User` roles
- [ ] Create AlloyDB IAM database user on your AlloyDB cluster
- [ ] Login as database admin user (ex. `postgres` user) and grant the new IAM database user the proper database privileges to the appropriate tables etc.

Comment: Is last step really needed? Right now we have multiple predefined roles that we can grant when creating the user.
https://cloud.google.com/alloydb/docs/database-users/about#predefined-role

Comment: when you say "predefined roles" do you mean IAM roles or database level roles? (edit: I see mentioned link points at database level roles, which if you can grant while creating would probably suffice).

Comment: I mean predefined database roles like `alloydbsuperuser`, also creating AlloyDB user is supported by terraform (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/alloydb_user), which means we can create & grant database roles with single IaaC resource definition.
That's why I asked if still some manual action with logging in as `postgres` user is required.